# Update model obtained from keras YOLOV8Detector to Apple MLPackage/CoreML

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, coreml, coremltools

I trained a `YOLOV8Detector` model using a `yolo_v8_xs_backbone` backbone by following this tutorial on KerasCV [Efficient Object Detection with YOLOV8 and KerasCV](https://keras.io/examples/vision/yolov8/) and training it on a [different dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/nguyngiabol/colorful-fashion-dataset-for-object-detection)

After some times, I was able to get predictions and visualise them as explained in the tutorial:

[image: 29d5951f-5e90-4b16-a0b8-987f443afbc4]

I would like to use this model inside an apple iOS application, so I used the `coremltools` package to convert it. However, it seems that the "outputs" produced by kerascv is not exactly the one expected by the apple world.

Once the model is trained, I can ask for a prediction:

```py
 images, y_true = next(iter(dataset.take(1)))
 y_pred = model.predict(images) // y_pred is a dictionary
```

`y_pred` is a dictionary of with those keys `['boxes', 'confidence', 'classes', 'num_detections']`

Using Netron, I can take a look at the shape of a model expected by the apple world

[image]

[image]

The goal here would to be able to have a mlpackage file where the preview mode is usable from Xcode:

[image: Xcode MLMOdel preview mode]

How can I modify/reshape the model generated from kerascv so instead of outputting dictionaries, I can have a model that outputs the confidence and coordinates answer as two separate outputs?

I have found some elements on this link with [MobileNetv2 and SSD](https://machinethink.net/blog/mobilenet-ssdlite-coreml/) but I am not sure how to apply those elements in this case

Comment: I am not familiar with coreml, but what is the blocker here? How about wrapping the model prediction to a method and return only desired outputs?

Comment: I wanted to take advantages of default integration with the vision framework and be able to use the preview mode when opening the model on Xcode.

Comment: 'default integration with the vision framework' - what do you mean? Also, you may not able to reconfig the above model as kerascv desinged to give such ouput as dict.

Comment: I will update my post to add explanation

Comment: if your model is a yolov8.pt model, you can simply use Ultralytics built-in export to coreML model. I describe mine here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77541935/inconsistent-object-detection-performance-between-yolov8n-pytorch-and-converted

Comment: Yep but commercial license . Trying to avoid it by understanding some basics but this may be too optimistic!